# Dynamically created DOM manipulation button not firing event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function to add and remove a field but the remove function doesnt work somehow.

HTML:

```
<div id="parts">
    Part
    <input type="text" id="auto_part" name="auto_part" />
                <br />
    Description
    <input type="text" id="auto_description" name="auto_description" />
                <br />
</div>
    <a href="#" id="addField">Add another part</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
var scntDiv = $('#parts');
var i = $('#parts input').size();

$('#addField').on('click', function() {
    $('<br /><div id="parts"><span>Part</span> <input type="text" id="auto_part'+i+'" name="auto_part'+i+'" /><br />').appendTo(scntDiv);
    $('<span>Description</span> <input type="text" id="auto_description'+i+'" name="auto_description'+i+'" /> <br />').appendTo(scntDiv);
    $('<input type="hidden" id="row_count" name="row_count" value="" />').appendTo(scntDiv);
    $('<a href="#" id="removefield">Remove</a></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
});

$('#removefield').on('click', function() { 
    if( i > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('div').remove();
            i--;
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

The problem must have to do with this line:

```
$('#removefield').on('click', function() {
```

It doesnt pass that condition.
When I click on Remove it doesnt do anything at all it just scrolls to the top.

Comment: also `ID`'s should be unique

Comment: The dynamic creation is only half of the problem. I'm voting for reopening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are binding the `click` handler to the elements that are present in the DOM. But, your `#removefield` element is being dynamically added. So, the event handler is not attached to it.

You can use `.on()` to use event delegation and handle also future elements. Also, you may want to use classnames instead of and `id` attributes. `id` attributes need to be unique, but you can set the classname to as many elements as you want.

```
<a href="#" class="removefield">Remove</a>
```

```
$("#parts").on("click", ".removefield", function() { 
  /* ... */
});
```

---

The reason why your `"Remove"` link doesn't work is because you are adding the dynamic `<div>` element by parts hence making it invalid markup. You should be adding it all together at once. For example,

```
$('#addField').on('click', function () {
    var part = '<div id="parts' + i + '"><span>Part</span> <input type="text" id="auto_part' + i + '" name="auto_part' + i + '" /><br/>' +
        '<span>Description</span> <input type="text" id="auto_description' + i + '" name="auto_description' + i + '" /> <br />' +
        '<input type="hidden" id="row_count' + i + '" name="row_count' + i + '" value="" />' +
        '<a href="#" class="removefield' + i + '">Remove</a></div>';
    scntDiv.after(part);
    i++;
    return false;
});
```

```
$(document).on("click", ".removefield", function() {
    if( i > 2 ) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
```

[You can see it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/YFwrM/)

Comment: This works, but when I press remove now it removes all the parts divs $(this).parents('#parts').remove();

Comment: @SinanSamet, that means your selector was wrong to start with. Can you fix your HTML layout? I don't think you are appending the elements where it seems you want them

Comment: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.nl/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html In that example it does work with the same name id and just removes the <p> its in instead of all

Comment: @SinanSamet, I can't see how that link is relevant for what you asked or I said

Comment: That does work but when it has a div around it, it removes that div aswell. In my case the container. http://jsfiddle.net/jQj23/2/

Comment: @SinanSamet, you need to [use `.parent()` instead of `.parents()`](http://jsfiddle.net/YFwrM/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#removefield').live("click", function() {
```

Comment: `live()` was removed in jQuery version 1.9 and was depreciated in 1.7. Use `on()`